# Display the first tag assigned to a post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

Originally I was trying to include the *first* tag of a post above the post on the homepage, using the following:

```
$tags_i = 0;
$tags = get_the_tags();
if ($tags) {
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tags_i++;
    if ($tags_i == 1) { ?>
      <h3><a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a></h3>
    <?php
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is that this actually grabs the first tag in *alphabetical* order (it seems at least). I was originally hoping to grab the first tag assigned to that post.

**I was wondering if** I would be able to use **custom tag** to achieve this. I've never used custom tag types, and I can't really find much information on how they work, so any additional info would be helpful. Or, if you can suggest a solution to my problem, that would also be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you define 'first'? Taxonomy terms don't have an order, and any term is just as much 'first' as any other term.

Comment: Perhaps your original problem would be better suited by asking how to define a 'primary tag' via custom meta.

Answer (score 0):

Assign taxonomy terms (ie tags) to a post in a specific order has no sense form me unless the taxonomy is hierarchical. The core tags taxonomy is no-hierarchical and category is hierarchical. So, you can define a hierarchical custom taxonomy or use the built-in category taxonomy.

Think in a natural flow of description terms. In a no-hierarchical context, what description term should be the first? There is no reason to put one over another, **you can order them just like you can order a string**. In a hierarchical taxonomy the order can be define as you want or need.